# How to parse a String of "hh:mm:ss.SSS" into a DateTime

Tags: parsing, date, datetime, dart

The format of "new DateTime.now()" will print following output:

```
2015-05-20 07:34:43.018
```

By having only the time as a String in the correct format (`"07:34:43.018"`), how do I parse the time to a DateTime object? The usage of the intl package does not support the mentioned format AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By prefixing the Date in front of the time, DateTime would be able to parse the given String.

```
DateTime parse(String timeValue) {
   var prefix  = '0000-01-01T';
   return DateTime.parse(prefix + timeValue);
}
```

If you also only want to display the time afterwards, format your DateTime variable accordingly:

```
String format(DateTime value) {
   return "${value.hour}:${value.minute}:${value.second}.${value.millisecond}";
}
```

I've mainly had to parse the String for calculations (difference) with other time values.