# Parsing 24 HR Time to DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart

I am attempting to convert the following 2HR time in String to a DateTime, so that I manage it appropriately.

```
"1800"
```

This question came close, but no one answered how to convert the String into a valid DateTime.

[How to convert time stamp string from 24 hr format to 12 hr format in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270847/how-to-convert-time-stamp-string-from-24-hr-format-to-12-hr-format-in-dart)

**Attempt 1:**

`DateTime.parse("1800")` -

> Invalid Date Format

Attempt 2:

`DateTime.ParseExact("1800")` -

> This doesn't seem to exist, although it shows up on various

Still no luck and need a second pair of eyes to point out the obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time by itself is not a datetime so you could do something like:

```
DateTime myTime(DateTime baseDate, String hhmm) {
  assert(hhmm.length == 4, 'invalid time');
  final _hours = int.parse(hhmm.substring(0, 2));
  final _mins = int.parse(hhmm.substring(2, 2));
  return DateTime(baseDate.year, baseDate.month, baseDate.day, _hours, _mins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.parse` expects to parse dates with times, not just times. (You can't even create a `DateTime` object without a date!)

[Some people generate a dummy date string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30341272/), but in your case you could trivially parse it with `int.parse` and then apply appropriate division and remainder operations:

```dart
var rawTime = int.parse('1800');
var hour = rawTime ~/ 100;
var minute = rawTime % 100;
```

Also see [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/) for more general `DateTime` parsing.